# model.eval() should use to measure accuracy on training set pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

During training phase, at the epoch 69, I got the following result

- train :     Loss: 0.201644404 Acc: 0.887417219(670/755)
- validation: Loss: 0.371976876 Acc: 0.880000000(66/75)

For testing phase, I load model at this epoch, and test again on this train and validation set:

- train set: Got 735 / 755 with accuracy 97.35
- validation: accuracy same as training phase

During training phase:

- I call model.eval() before calculating accuracy on validation set, but not for train set

During test phase:

- I call model.eval() before calculating accuracy on both train and validation set

The question is

1. which training accuracy should I rely on? 0.88 during training phase, or 0.97 during test phase?
2. As Andrew Ng has pointed out, the difference between training accuracy and validation accuracy may imply overfit. If I choose 0.88, then my model is not overfit, but if I choose 0.97, my model may be overfit?

Comment: you should also use model.eval() on the train set. Therefore 0.97 is probably the value to rely on

Comment: Trust the one with `.eval`. You use `model.eval()` to turn off some layers that help during training but make things worse when predict/validate.

Comment: Thanks you all. Is there any link or detail explained about this?